# WP Twenty Seventeen: menu on mobile expands but doesn't scroll down to show the menu items

Tags: jquery, wordpress, hamburger-menu

When menu is clicked in mobile view it just expands but it doesn't scroll down to menu section to show the listed items (in my case 5 menu items).

I've been looking in navigation.js, global.js and jquery.scrollTo.js files and to me it seems that it is somewhere here:

```
// Set the active submenu initial state.
        container.find( '.current-menu-ancestor > .sub-menu' ).addClass( 'toggled-on' );

        container.find( '.dropdown-toggle' ).click( function( e ) {
            var _this = $( this ),
                screenReaderSpan = _this.find( '.screen-reader-text' );

            e.preventDefault();
            _this.toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );
            _this.next( '.children, .sub-menu' ).toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );

            _this.attr( 'aria-expanded', _this.attr( 'aria-expanded' ) === 'false' ? 'true' : 'false' );

            screenReaderSpan.text( screenReaderSpan.text() === twentyseventeenScreenReaderText.expand ? twentyseventeenScreenReaderText.collapse : twentyseventeenScreenReaderText.expand );
        });
    }

    initMainNavigation( $( '.main-navigation' ) );

    masthead       = $( '#masthead' );
    menuToggle     = masthead.find( '.menu-toggle' );
    siteNavContain = masthead.find( '.main-navigation' );
    siteNavigation = masthead.find( '.main-navigation > div > ul' );
```

or here:

```
// Enable menuToggle.
(function() {

    // Return early if menuToggle is missing.
    if ( ! menuToggle.length ) {
        return;
    }

    // Add an initial value for the attribute.
    menuToggle.attr( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );

    menuToggle.on( 'click.twentyseventeen', function() {
        siteNavContain.toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );

        $( this ).attr( 'aria-expanded', siteNavContain.hasClass( 'toggled-on' ) );
    });
})();
```

Can anyone help and make this work?

The idea is: when i click on menu icon, to slowly scrolls down to show the menu items.